# Determine the number of "clumps" in array of integers

Tags: java

A clump in an array is defined as a series of 2 or more adjacent elements of the same value. For example:

```
{3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 2, 2}
```

contains 2 clumps comprising 1 clump of 5's and one of 2's. (assume every array has at least 1 element)

I need to write a method to return the number of clumps in a given array:

```
public int countClumps(int[] nums) {
    int totalClumps = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int a = 1;
        while (nums[i] == nums[i+a] && (i+a) < nums.length) {
            a++;
        }
        if (a != 1) {
            totalClumps++;
            i += (a - 1);
        }
        a = 1;
    }
}
```

This is the closest I have gotten to solving.  What would I change so that it works?

Comment: Looks interesting, but you have to check that `num[i+a]` doesn't reach out of the array.

Comment: Two loops are not needed You can achive the answer by using just one loop `int lastNum=array[0];int totalClumps= 0;for(int i=1;i<array.length;i++){if(array[i] == lastNum){totalClumps++;}else{lastNum= A[i];}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code:

1. `i+=a`. This increases i's value correctly, but then the `for-loop` increments it too. I'd recommend using a `while` loop, and incrementing `i` by `a` without any conditions (i.e., `i+=a` even when `a` is 1).
2. In the `while` loop, you need to check that `i+a` is within the range of the array.

Comment: I understand part 2 of your answer and made those changes above.  I don't quite understand how I would implement part 1 of your answer using a while loop.  I understand that `i` gets incremented again in the `for-loop`, so I made some changes to the conditional.

Comment: @Bronzz3n yes, this is what I was suggesting. Do you still have issues?

Comment: Put the condition checking first in the while loop. If you check the condition after accessing the element, essentially it can give an address access issue.

Comment: Yep it works now!  Was just double checking that was what you meant.  Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below one.

```
int[] arr = new int[]{3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 2, 2};

IntStream.of(arr).filter( data -> Collections.frequency(Arrays.asList(arr), data) >1)
.distinct()
.forEach( data -> { System.out.println(data );} );
```

Output is 5 and 2